# Escribir en archivos con Tokenizer

Tags: java, tokens

Tengo un archivo separado por pipes `"|"` donde con `tokenizer` estoy leyendo los campos, ahora lo que quisiera haces es que los parámetros se actualicen en automático, lo único que necesitaría seria reescribir el dato pero únicamente de ese espacio, la manera en que los leo es la siguiente:

```
public class ReadLine(){
  String line;
  BufferedReader brMTOPDev = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mboppath + 
  "mtop_device"));

        while((line = brMTOPDev.readLine()) != null){
            StringTokenizer sTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line , "|");
            while(sTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String statMTOP = sTokenizer.nextToken().toString();
                String startCap = sTokenizer.nextToken().toString();
                String statCap = sTokenizer.nextToken().toString();

                //System.out.println(line);
            }
}
```

para escribir un valor en startCap cual seria la manera de hacerlo? He leído varios sobre como escribir pero no he encontrado nada así

los Valores del archivo son los siguientes

```
0|1|0
```

y los quiero cambiar a

```
0|0|0
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que estás preguntando. Que es que "los parametros se actualicen en automático". Que significa "reescribir el dato pero unicamente de ese espacio". Y aclarar "para escribir un valor es startCap cual seria la manera de hacerlo?"

Comment: No se entiende muy bien.